# Best way to automate daily reports in excel and export in vba and run procedures

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, vba

What is the best way to automate daily reports, I have excel file which i get from daily basis and then i make some changes in excel file like remove, add column and then i import in sql server and then run procedures mannually, i want to do it automatically.what is the best method i will use.

Comment: Your question is too vague. How do you 'import in sql'? what procedures are you running manually? are these procedure in VBA? In short, if I get what you are asking (which I'm not entirely sure I do), then most of this can be done through VBA. But you will have to provide a lot more information

Comment: SSIS (Sql Server Integration Services) is the tool that Microsoft provides for automating the kind of process you're talking about.  There's quite a bit to learn about, but it is an extremely powerful and useful set of resources.  VBA is a scripting language.  Although you can accomplish many things with it, keep in mind that it is slow, clumsy to maintain, doesn't scale well at all, and does not lend itself to source control or versioning.

Comment: @Greenspark hello green, i cannot run ssis script task as well as cannot define variables in ssis because in my company i dont have rights for that.

Comment: @Greenspark only i can do is transformation and data importing

Comment: @Zac i am running procedure from sql server

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using the Excel file, you can try to use the AutoHotkey to emulate a Human.

If you want to create a real automation, one of the options is:

1. Develop an SSIS package that creates the Excel output file, in this package you will input all logic and data transformations.
2. Publish the SSIS package into the SQL Server
3. Create a job to run the SSIS Package